# If comets are thought to brought water on Earth could there be water in form of ice on the neighbouring Moon's poles?

Tags: water, evaporation, moon, comets

If comets are thought to brought water on Earth could there be water in form of ice on the neighbouring Moon's poles? As water can easly evaporate if there is no atmosphere as in the case of Moon's equator can it 'survive' on cold places like the poles of the Moon?

Comment: from NASA - [Ice on the Moon](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/ice/ice_moon.html)